# How to capture from regex in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I am running this piece of code so that I can match the branch name with a pattern and create port based on which:

`nano test.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

branch="3.2.1"

re='([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)'

if [[ $branch =~ "master" ]]; then
  port=3000
  echo $port
elif [[ $branch =~ $re ]]; then
  port="300${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  echo $port
else
  echo "no match found!"
fi
```

and
`bash test.sh`

I am expecting `3003` but it is returning `3.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

should be `300${BASH_REMATCH[1]`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

branch="3.2.1"

re='([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)'

if [[ $branch =~ "master" ]]; then
  port=3000
  echo $port
elif [[ $branch =~ $re ]]; then
  port="300${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo $port
else
  echo "no match found!"
fi
```